# ons-back-button goes back to home instead of previous page in stack

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I recently updated a Cordova mobile app to use OnsenUI v1.3.8 (in order to fix a problem with broken back buttons when viewing the app on iOS 8.4). The problem I'm now seeing is that the back buttons throughout the app, send you all the way back home. Even levels down in the app, pressing the back button takes you to the previous page, then seems to fire another event to go back again.

I have the following syntax in my index.html (home) page:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
  <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="main.html">
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
```

In the rest of my app, I'm using the following syntax:

```
<ons-toolbar>
  <div class="left animated fadeIn">
     <ons-back-button><div class="animated fadeIn">Back</div></ons-back-button>
  </div>
  <div class="center animated fadeIn">{{ title }}</div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

Main.html is simply...

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

[EDIT]
Below is the HTML behind the button/s:

```
<ons-back-button class="ng-scope">
     <span class="toolbar-button--quiet " ng-click="" style="height: 44px; line-height: 0; padding: 0; position: relative;">
       <i class="ion-ios-arrow-back ons-back-button__icon" style="vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent; height: 44px; line-height: 44px; font-size: 36px; margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 2px; width: 16px; display: inline-block; padding-top: 1px;"></i><span style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; line-height: 44px; height: 44px;" class="back-button__label"><div class="animated fadeIn ng-scope">Back</div></span>
</span>
    </ons-back-button>
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce this on an iOS 8.4 device with Onsen UI 1.3.8 without success. I created a simple app with a navigator and pushed a few pages but the back button only triggers one pop.

Can you create a small example that reproduces this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a small example to push. I've also downgraded Onsen to v1.1.4 and included FastClick 1.0.2, yet I see the same ghost clicking.

Comment: I see. Do you have any custom CSS on the back button that might cause the extra clicks?

Comment: I don't see any custom CSS that could be causing it. I updated my original post with the HTML behind the button/s.

Comment: This is simply not enough information to go by. Can you include how you are pushing pages to "myNavigator" and/or how you are navigating from the parent page to child pages.